# Mysql form new optimize query

Tags: mysql

I have Four Tables in database,

users, count, coupon, account

Need number of users from following conditions:

1. Select All Users from users table then
2. Select from count where users are not in the list of last 14 days then
3. Select users which are not in the list, to check that there are in coupon table. If they are not in coupon table then take those users id then
4. Select account table and check that these users have any count or insertion in the account table. If yes then set all those users in an array or print it out as a result.

Please anybody help me in forming good query?

Thanks!

Comment: what you have done yet?

Comment: Could you type out the exact relations between all tables. It wouldn't hurt to type it all out. Don't forget putting `count` between backticks (“\`”), because `count` is a reserved mysql word for count operations.`

Comment: user with count (one to many), users with coupon (one to one), users with account (one to many)

Comment: also, list the table structures of anything that would be needed for this query... common primary/foreign keys... etc

Comment: That's what I meant by typing it all out. Seems like a very weird table structure and sql though. Added the concluded solution based on story though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right take users

- who **aren't** in the count table for the last 14 days 
  and
- who **aren't** in the coupon table.
  and
- who **are** in the account table

Seems like a weird sql but here is an example:

```
SELECT  
    * 
FROM 
    user
WHERE user_id NOT IN
    ( 
        SELECT 
            user_id 
        FROM 
            `count` 
        WHERE
            DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 14 DAY) <= date_column
    )
AND user_id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT
            user_id
        FROM
            coupon
    )
AND user_id IN
    (
        SELECT
            user_id
        FROM
            account
    )
```

If this isn't right, your explanation of what you want is wrong and should be clarified . 
Everything could be wrong with this sql, because I don't know your columns (user id? date?) .But I think you can change the sql to your liking.

Comment: AND user_id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT
            user_id
        FROM
            coupon
    ) can I use where clause here after coupon like where coupon_code = 'xyz'??